# Flutter How to use "forEach" method to add String to new List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "person": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 18
      },
      {
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "person": [
      {
        "name": "Oliver",
        "age": 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "C",
    "person": null
  }
]
```

I want to add a `List<String>` to each element of this data: `['{$name.toLowerCase()}_${{age}']` like this:

```
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "newList": [
      "john_18",
      "jack_21"
    ],
    "person": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 18
      },
      {
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": 21
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "newList": [
      "oliver_24"
    ],
    "person": [
      {
        "name": "Oliver",
        "age": 24
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "C",
    "newList": null,
    "person": null
  }
]
```

pls help me, here is the code I am trying to do it:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main(){
  var json = '[{"group":"A","person":[{"name":"John","age":18},{"name":"Jack","age":21}]},{"group":"B","person":[{"name":"Oliver","age":24}]},{"group":"C","person":null}]';
  final data = dataFromJson(json);
  data.forEach((e) {
    if (e != null) {
      List<String> _list = [];
      e.person.forEach((p) {
        if (p != null) {
          String x = p.name.toLowerCase().toString();
          String y = p.age.toString();
          String z = '${x}_$y';
          _list.add(z);
          e.newList = _list;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  data.forEach((e) => print(e.newList));
}

List<Data> dataFromJson(String str) => List<Data>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Data.fromJson(x)));

String dataToJson(List<Data> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Data {
  Data({
    this.group,
    this.person,
    this.newList = const [],
  });

  String group;
  List<Person> person;
  List<String> newList;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        group: json["group"] == null ? null : json["group"],
        person: json["person"] == null ? null : List<Person>.from(json["person"].map((x) => Person.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "group": group == null ? null : group,
        "person": person == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(person.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Person {
  Person({
    this.name,
    this.age,
  });

  String name;
  int age;

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Person(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        age: json["age"] == null ? null : json["age"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "age": age == null ? null : age,
      };
}
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: you need `map` method, not `forEach`

Comment: Could you pls give me details of the code that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative if you want to use `forEach`:

```dart
final String data = ...;
final List<dynamic> json = jsonDecode(data);

// Create a copy of json
final List<dynamic> json2 = List.from(json);

// For each {"group": ..., "person": ...}
json2.forEach((child) {
  // Create a new key joining each person's name and age
  child["newList"] = child["person"]?.map((child) => child["name"] + "_" + child["age"]).toList();
});
```